# NSRegularExpression - Probleme with a Pattern

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

i've wrote a little program to find a string in a string which works fine so far. But i have a problem with NSRegularExpression - i need the right Pattern for my special case and stuck.

```
NSString *strRegExp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?trunk/%@/%@/+\\([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.])+/Host-1", inputstrse , inputstrsno];

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:strRegExp options:        NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];

NSArray *arrayOfAllMatches = [regex matchesInString:inputurl options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [inputurl length])];
```

The NSRegularExpression pattern should match string the look like this:

```
trunk/%@/%@/some-text-1/Host-1
trunk/test/1/5-text-text/Host-1
```

Where trunk/%@/%@/ and /Host-1 stays always the same. Only the part in the middle is variable and always looks like this:

```
NUMBER-Some-Text -> 5-Hello-World -> /trunk/test/1/5-hello-world/Host-1
```

I've tried it with different RegExp as you see here: "?trunk/%@/%@/+\([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.])+/Host-1", but i still seems not to work, maybe someone can help me.

Maybe there is a Probleme when i build the pattern with:

```
 NSString *strRegExp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?trunk/%@/%@/+\\([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.])+/Host-1", inputstrse , inputstrsno];
```

And use it later like that:

```
regularExpressionWithPattern:strRegExp
```

I hope someone can help me - i'm new to RegularExpressions.

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: inputse is something like: Hello-Test-1 or Hallo or Hallo-1 
inputsno is just a number from 1-30
inputurl is plain html code from a website.

Comment: So you have a bunch of text and want to pick out the parts that look like `/trunk/test/1/5-hello-world/Host-1`?

Comment: Right were the Part "5-hello-world" always changes but looks similar its also a number followed by a "-" followed by some text and maybe again followed by "-" and text several times.

Comment: Alright, will post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, expressing a Regex as "I want to match a number of letters, then a dash, then a number" and so on is the easiest way to construct one. Also, using a tool such as http://www.regexr.com simplifies a lot.

From what I understand you want to match the following:

```
trunk/test/1/[some number]-[some text]-[some other text]/Host-1
```

If so, then the following regular expression should cut it:

```
trunk\/test\/1\/[0-9]*-[a-zA-Z]*-[a-zA-Z]*\/Host-1
```

It does the following:

1. `trunk\/test\/1\/`: Match the constant string `trunk/test/1/` (The backslashes are escapes)
2. `[0-9]*-`: Match any number of digits followed by a `-`
3. `[a-zA-Z]*-`: Match any number of letters followed by a `-`
4. `[a-zA-Z]*`: Match any number of letters
5. `\/Host-1`: Match the constant string `/Host-1/`

Here is a link to RegExr which you can use if you want to experiment with different input data or changes to the regex: http://regexr.com/39tgn

The following string was provided in the comments: `trunk\test\/1\/.*\/Host-1`. It's a bit less strict but does the job as well.

Comment: Just one last thing: It works but there is one problem: trunk/test/1/[some number]-[some text]-[some other text]/Host-1 works fine with trunk\/test\/1\/[0-9]*-[a-zA-Z]*-[a-zA-Z]*\/Host-1 but in some cases there are more than two [some text] areas like: trunk/test/1/[some number]-[some text]-[some other text]-[some other text]/Host-1 it ranges from only 1 [some text] section up to 10 - what can i do to match all cases with one RegExp?

Comment: Got it working with "trunk\/%@\/%@\/.*\/Host-1". Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that it's working for you! Please mark my answer as accepted if it worked. :) I'll update it with the new string you provided.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Objective-C but your regex has a bunch of oddities, if I remove those I get something that I think you'd want to achieve.

Your first character is a `?`, that can't be, it's a quantifier in regex that says something about the preceding character (or class or group). If it's the first character, there is no preceding char.

`/+\\` <-- unsure what you were trying to do here, but it means *'1 or more `/` followed by `\`'*

`[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]` can be done much shorter like: `[\w.-]` and if you place the `+` within the parentheses it will capture the entire unknown string in capture group 1.

*From comments:* So `%@` is a variable text, the first is always just letters, the 2nd is always just numbers. That would be `[a-zA-Z]+` and `\d+` respectively in a regex. But actually I would use `[^/]+` (any character that isn't `/`) so that the code doesn't break when someone puts a different character in this path like `trunk/this_text/4/.../Host-1` which would break on the `_`.

**Combined this makes *(changed after comments)*:**

```
trunk/[^/]+/[^/]+/([\w.-]+)/Host-1
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OyC3VSZWn4INvVSq)

**Now note** that this is without escaping to get the proper string into the regex engine, but if Objective-C is anything like C# then a string started with `@"..."` doesn't need escaping.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer!!!

trunk/test/1/5-text-text/Host-1 is the Text that _should_ match. It's always the same: statictext/varitext/varinumber/RandomTextNumbersAnd-/statictext.

Comment: @MillerPI Changed the answer accordingly :)

Comment: Still not working - to make it more clearly the string have only 1 unknown part. /KnownTextStatic/KnownTextThatcomesFromVariable/KnownNumberThatComesFromVariable/UnknownPart/KnownTextStatic where UnkownPart is a string which contains Numbers from 1 till 30, lower and uppercase charakters and minuses("-"). So i need a pattern which matches sometext/UNKNOWN/sometext as explained above. Hope this makes it clear now

Comment: Got it with: "trunk\/%@\/%@\/.*\/Host-1" Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know, it looks useful to me.